Issue with React's createRoot Function
I'm encountering an issue with React's createRoot function in my project. When I attempt to use ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />);, I receive the following error in the console: Uncaught Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

I have verified that the element with id="root" exists in my HTML file.

You just try to use the below format,
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';
import './index.css';    
    
const domNode = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(domNode);
    
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
       <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);

refer this document link: createRoot
Additional point: ReactDOM.render was deprecated in the ReactJS v18.0.0 (Removed: ReactDOM.render)

What about this format will change the functionality the OP currently has? The OP's code is doing the exact same thing just without the 2 temporary variables. The error is pretty clearly about a missing DOM element not a syntax error or use of deprecated API
